# how to use android Internal API's

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me, how to import Android hidden/internal API's into my application?

For example, `com.android.internal.telephony`. How to import this APi into application?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the classes are available at runtime, but not compile time, yes you can't compile against them directly in your code but you can still try to load them via reflection. We used this in Android 1.x to load a hidden internal class that controlled the LED light on some devices. It is difficult since every method call turns into several lines of calls to `java.lang.reflect` classes. See here:

http://www.google.com/codesearch#k59QJW14udA/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/FlashlightManager.java

Of course, these APIs or classes would not at all be guaranteed to be present on all devices, and could change or disappear, so this is brittle. And it may be that there's a `SecurityManager` protecting access to certain internals too, I don't know.